# Service calling another service within the same IIS but not passing through extra data in SOAP message

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis, soap

Basically one web service API is calling another service which is serving as business logic layer. When API is calling BLL it is suppose to send some application details in SOAP message itself and it's not doing it resulting in and exception saying this data is missing.

I'm not sure how those details are added because the service class is extending on some DLL that have the method to add those in. When run locally I can see those details being passed through.

I have this legacy application that was working OK until last week. Didn't change the application at all but someone might have changed IIS settings.

Is there a setting that could influence sending those details with the SOAP request between .NET services?